# Network Programming: Nomenclature Questions

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, network-protocols

So I am looking to get into network programming.

Specifically for a real time strategy game (in Unity 3D). I've done some basic GET and REQUEST stuff before, but I'm curious as to what I will need for doing real time game programming over a network.

My questions about the programming nomenclature are:

-What is the name of programming ("network programming" is too broad) involved in coding real time game networks?

-Can I do real time network programming with JSON or is there another technology I need to use?

-What search terms should I use to research network programming further (as what I've been pulling up has been to broad)?

Thank you!

**Update:**

Adding to the helpful question below, here is a good link explaining the different types of Authoritative Servers.

http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/fast_paced_multiplayer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity 4 uses a built-in version of [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/) to achieve network programming, typically referred to as *Unity Networking*.

Rather than using GET requests or sending JSON messages, you generally use the various [Network](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.html) APIs that Unity offers:

- The host starts up with [`Network.InitializeServer`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.InitializeServer.html).
- Clients connect to the host with [`Network.Connect`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.Connect.html).
- GameObjects that need to be synchronised across all players should have a [NetworkView](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/NetworkView.html) component attached to them; objects are then synched automatically without needing much effort on your part (for a basic object anyway).
- [Remote Procedure Calls](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-RPCDetails.html) let you invoke functions on clients.

Data is transferred with UDP packets since things need to happen quickly without ACK packets being sent back and forth, though there are [different options](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-StateSynchronization.html) to ensure the packets are ordered reliably within Unity if needed.

The Unity [Network Reference Guide](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NetworkReferenceGuide.html) is a good read.

Comment: or do what i did and spend 3 months building a bit packing socket based server infrastructure and client :) Evil but you definitely learn a lot lol.